# Parse: Create/Save New User without signUp

Tags: ios, parse-platform

It seems Parse does not let me create new users, unless the sign up block is called.

It also seems that Parse doesn't let you edit username/password unless that user is currentUser logged in.

The goal is to create a new user, save him, and when they sign up at a later point, I can recognize their previous user account, or create one if that does not exist.

Signup/Login block methods are not the answer, I do not want to change the current user.

```
                   PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
                  PFUser *userAgain = (PFUser *)[query getObjectWithId:user.objectId];
                  userAgain.username = "another_username";
 // This will throw an exception, since the PFUser is not authenticated
                  [userAgain save]
```

P.S. 
Here's the elevator pitch. This is a chat app (signup w/ phone#). I want to invite users in my contacts (but not on app) to a "chatroom". So i create a user account for their phone#. When they signup, I login that previously created user (checking phone#s) , and they see my "chatroom" in their inbox.

Comment: could you not use an anonymous user? : https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-anonymous/iOS

Comment: Yes! I think i will. I have to check for `isVerified` against the phone number txt message. Then dispose of any unwanted automatic users (if there are any). Then! I may be able to create accounts for people who aren't on the app yet.

Comment: Let me know if this ended up as the answer for you and I will put it into an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the steps I had to take.

**On the Signin End**

1. Enable `enableAutomaticUser` for anonymous user.
2. `PFQuery` for user registering to make sure his account doesn't exist based on his `phoneNumber`
3. If `PFQuery` has an object, save this `PFUser`, we will login with his credentials AFTER and IF the text message verification is `true`.

**On Signup End**

1. For each `phoneNumber`, make sure a user doesn't already exist. If it does, forget that `phoneNumber`, add the `PFuser`
2. Enumerate each `phoneNumber` for Register using the REST API

   ```
   - (void) saveNewUserWithPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber
    {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/users"];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setURL:url];
     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:API KEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [request setValue:APP ID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];

   NSDictionary *dict = @{@"username":phoneNumber,@"password":phoneNumber,PF_USER_PHONENUMBER:phoneNumber, PF_USER_ISVERIFIED: @NO};
    NSError *error;
    NSData *postBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
   [request setHTTPBody:postBody];

    // Send request to Parse and parse returned data
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                  queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                          if (!connectionError) {
                              NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                              NSString *objectId = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"objectId"];
                              [_arrayOfSelectedUsers addObject:[PFUser objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:objectId]];
                              x--;
                              //If we finished all the phone numbers, create the chatroom;
                              if (x == 0){
                                  [self actionSend];
                              }

                          } else {

                          }
                      }];
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using `enableAutomaticUser`. If you add a relationship between the user and some other object in the data store then that user would be saved. I haven't tried doing it to make sure that a new anonymous user is not created before you set the e-mail and password (or request a password reset), but it should work.

You can set the e-mail and password of the user and then save it.

Comment: So one user creates an account for another user and then sends an invite (to an e-mail address) ?

Comment: That should work. So I would create essentially a `User2` class with users waiting to signIn/Register, then I check against that for  `if (currentUser) ` . I believe anonymous users are generated after first  `  [PFuser currentuser]  ` save method. Background cleanup may be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, here's the elevator pitch. This is a chat app (signup w/ phone#). I want to invite users in my contacts (but not on app) to a "chatroom". So i create a user account for their phone#. When they signup, I login that previously created user (checking phone#s) , and they see my "chatroom" in their inbox.

Comment: Ok, so you can create a user with the phone# for the username and password and then find that user again later and replace the username and password and set the e-mail. You will needs to ask for the phone# they were invited with as part of the signup somehow...

Comment: Yes, that is setup to your description. But `[PFuser new] saveInBackground]` crashes the app. Even if I don't save a username/password.

Comment: Use the signup API but with the phone number in place of future values to be completed - you always need to be able to query for an existing user with the phone number as the username anyway

Comment: Signup API... I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cached the password of the original user, you can log back in with that user after creating the new user. It seems a bit hackish, but it worked for me.

Comment: I would not recommend that.

Comment: @benjaminhallock Why is that? It works well for my use case, which is an admin creating sub-users.

Comment: Because I invented a better way.

Comment: That comes off a bit smug. While your way might be better for your specific use, I thought it was a interesting approach to add to the conversation for others.

Comment: Your way involved caching a private password in an unencrypted file system and potential never destroying the instance of the password, which could easily be read if someone was debugging the program.